# What's the best way to add a view under UINavigationBar in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

On ios7, a lot of apps (Apple Messages, Facebook Messenger, Calendar)have views appearing under the UINavigationBar, often with what seems to be standard animation. As it seems quite standard and looks a lot with a UIToolBar, I was looking for the standard way of implementing it but couldn't find anything.

Is there a better way to adding a UIToolBar to the UINavigationBar?

[image: Apple Messages]

Comment: Why not define your own custom UIView?

Comment: It looks more just like a simple view frame animation...

Comment: @MrBr you mean instead of a UIToolBar?

Comment: If you use a UIScrollView you could detect when that view is op top and show  / hide a custom view (with UIToolBar in it if you like) accordingly.

Comment: Look at the below simple approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should follow this simple approach.

- Add a `UIToolBar` like this.

  ```
  UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
  UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
  UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];

  NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, flexiableItem, item2, nil];
  self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
  [self.toolBar setItems:items];
  self.toolBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.toolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.1 blue:0.2 alpha:1];
  [self.contentView addSubview:self.toolBar];
  ```
- Add a Menu Button on Top navigation item

  ```
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleMenu:)];
  ```
- Now Implement `toggleMenu` function. Add a `BOOL` variable to track the movement.

  ```
  if(!moved) {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
      self.toolBar.alpha = 1;
      self.toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
  }];
  moved = YES;
  }else {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
      self.toolBar.alpha = 1;
      self.toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, -44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
  }];
  moved = NO;
  }
  ```
- Here is the attached [video](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/topToolBar.mov) for this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I had done. I was just wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: @BalramTiwari, bro could you please help me to take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376475/uinavigationbar-does-not-overlap-to-uicollectionview-in-swift-4?noredirect=1#comment79712072_46376475 ?