# Is it possible to add view behind navigation bar in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I wonder if its possible to add a view under the navigation bar in a `UITableViewController`?

What I would like to do is to add a view under the navigation bar in my `UITableViewController` so that I can add a search input / filter button to that view. But I want the view to have a fixed position under the navigation bar so that I can hide the navigationbar+view when swiping.

Right now storyboard only lets me add a view in the `UITableViewController`. And the new view is also swipeable. And the loading indicator shows up above the view when you swipe down.

[image]

Comment: Just put it in the header view, that's what they are for.

Comment: @DreamingInBinary what do you mean with header view? My navigation bar has an image in the center that you cant see on the image I provided. So I cant add any more items in the navigation bar. (New to ios-dev)

Comment: It means the header view of `UITableView`. Do not confuse with `sectionHeaderView`.

Comment: @Vive Sorry I only know of sectionHeaderView, do you have link / tutorial on this that I could check out? Thanks

Comment: Are you planning on using UISearchController? Or something custom?

Comment: @MarkBlythe something custom

Comment: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;`
I use this for search controller but if you are using a custom view it should be possible in a similar way. Replace `self.searchController.searchBar` with your custom search view. This adds it to the table header which looking at your screenshot should be right below the navigation bar.

Comment: OR Add a UIToolBar and customise that. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407977/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-view-under-uinavigationbar-in-ios7)

Comment: @MarkBlythe thanks alot! But the problem now is that the new item added will appear under the refreshControl. I would like it to be sticky/fixed under the navigation bar. Is this possible? I have alot of stuff going on so I would really not have to rewrite all - a solution is to have a view controller wrap a table view or embedd the table view VC inside a container view in the root VC

Comment: You should take a look into `UISearchController`, it will solve your problems.

Comment: @Vive the UISearchController will scroll with the table view I want it to be fixed under the navigation bar

Comment: UIToolbar should be fixed to navigation bar. The refresh control should be just below that.

Comment: I don't understand how do you want it to act. When you pull up it should both refresh and show the search bar? Or it should guess what user wants to do? Both sounds like a wrong UX and I'd reconsider this in your place :). Cheers.