# UINavigationBar does not overlap to UICollectionView in swift 4

Tags: uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, swift4, xcode9

I put Navigation bar inside UICollectionView in swift 4. 
When I scroll the collectionView, it does not goes to back layer and it overlaps to Navigation Bar.

[image]

[image]

```
 self.collectionview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0)
```

I also write this code but it does not work. I also unselect the "Under Top Bars" in Extend Edges in Attributes Inspector. 
 All the ways do not work. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can u please post more code?

Comment: @ViniApp, I didn't write any code bro. Just add above code bro

Comment: Header is a navigationBar or custom UIView ?

Comment: @Surjeet, this is CollectionView Controller bro. I put Navigation Bar inside it bro. I upload another screenshot bro. Please view it